# Table Background - The canvas of the image a link with the text on top of it?

Tags: html-table

Newbie and not sure the proper code to use here. The canvas of the image a link with the text on top of it

```
<td background="#" width="600" height="300" style="background-position: center top;">

                    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                    <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px;height:300px;">
                        <v:fill type="tile" src="#" />
                        <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
                    <![endif]-->
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to take you to a page, then wrap the entire thing in an anchor [(`a`) tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a):

```html
<a href="foo.html">
  <!-- So contentful -->
</a>
```

If you want it to simply have the pointer cursor up, then you can do it via the [`cursor` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor):

```html
<div style="cursor: pointer"></div>
```

Edit: You always want to have your `td` the top-most element within that table item.  Therefore, you can just create a `div` and put the styling and `cursor: pointer` onto that div with the content within it underneath the `td`.

Comment: Thank you for this but it didn't seem to work. I also have text on top of this image, not sure if that is adding to the problem.